# Can't execute "stat" on android 2.3.4 command not found

Tags: android, adb, android-2.2-froyo

So I am currently connected to my android phone using adb shell. When I do "stat file"
I get this message:

```
stat: not found
```

Do I need to install this script or what? Im on a 2.3.4 Gingerbread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the stat command is not available on the device. There is a very limited set of commands available. They are listed here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am following this guide. http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?3703-Backing-up-and-restoring-your-user-dictionary-ROOT-USERS-ONLY mind to take a quick look? The guy is even doing a grep and I suspect he is on windows because of his examples

Comment: Hi, I took a look at that site. Looks like he is talking to users with rooted phones. Not me I'm afraid. If you type 'set' at an android shell prompt you will see what your path on the device is set to. I had a look at all of these locations and could not find stat. It is possible that he installed these programs himself or is using a different phone/emulator to me. Not sure how you would even go about installing supplemental linux commands onto your phone - there be dragons :)

Comment: My phone is rooted though. so maybe my best bet is to use a different "phone terminal emulator" then.

Comment: The link in the answer does not list the available shell command on an Android device. It just lists the adb sub-commands, and very few shell commands by example.

Answer (score 2):

`stat` does not come with Android/[AOSP](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands).

If you run `ls /system/bin` you will get a list a lot shorter than what you are probably used to being able to do in most *NIX environments:

```
ATFWD-daemon
abcc
adb
am
app_process
applypatch
atrace
bdAddrLoader
bmgr
bootanimation
bridgemgrd
btnvtool
bu
bugreport
cat
chcon
chmod
chown
clatd
clear
cmp
conn_init
content
cp
dalvikvm
date
dd
debuggerd
dexopt
df
dhcpcd
diag_klog
diag_mdlog
dmesg
dnsmasq
drmserver
ds_fmc_appd
du
dumpstate
dumpsys
e2fsck
efsks
fsck_msdos
getenforce
getevent
getprop
getsebool
grep
gzip
hci_qcomm_init
hd
hostapd
id
ifconfig
iftop
ime
input
insmod
installd
ioctl
ionice
ip
ip6tables
iptables
keystore
kill
ks
linker
ln
load_policy
log
logcat
logwrapper
ls
lsmod
lsof
make_ext4fs
md5
mdnsd
media
mediaserver
mkdir
mksh
mm-qcamera-daemon
monkey
mount
mpdecision
mtpd
mv
nandread
ndc
netcfg
netd
netmgrd
netstat
newfs_msdos
nl_listener
notify
ping
pm
port-bridge
pppd
printenv
ps
qcks
qmuxd
qseecomd
racoon
radish
reboot
renice
requestsync
restorecon
rild
rm
rmdir
rmmod
rmt_storage
route
run-as
runcon
schedtest
schedtop
screencap
screenshot
sdcard
sendevent
sensors.qcom
sensorservice
service
servicemanager
setconsole
setenforce
setprop
setsebool
settings
sh
sleep
smd
start
stop
surfaceflinger
svc
sync
system_server
tc
thermald
toolbox
top
touch
uiautomator
umount
uptime
usbhub
usbhub_init
v4l2-qcamera-app
vdc
vmstat
vold
watchprops
wipe
wm
wpa_supplicant
```

No `stat`, as you can see. If you have root privileges, a simple solution is to install something like [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) which adds some such [*bread-and-butter* scripted functions](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands) as `stat` to your environment:

```
[
[[
acpid
addgroup
adduser
adjtimex
ar
arp
arping
ash
awk
basename
beep
blkid
brctl
bunzip2
bzcat
bzip2
cal
cat
catv
chat
chattr
chgrp
chmod
chown
chpasswd
chpst
chroot
chrt
chvt
cksum
clear
cmp
comm
cp
cpio
crond
crontab
cryptpw
cut
date
dc
dd
deallocvt
delgroup
deluser
depmod
devmem
df
dhcprelay
diff
dirname
dmesg
dnsd
dnsdomainname
dos2unix
dpkg
du
dumpkmap
dumpleases
echo
ed
egrep
eject
env
envdir
envuidgid
expand
expr
fakeidentd
false
fbset
fbsplash
fdflush
fdformat
fdisk
fgrep
find
findfs
flash_lock
flash_unlock
fold
free
freeramdisk
fsck
fsck.minix
fsync
ftpd
ftpget
ftpput
fuser
getopt
getty
grep
gunzip
gzip
hd
hdparm
head
hexdump
hostid
hostname
httpd
hush
hwclock
id
ifconfig
ifdown
ifenslave
ifplugd
ifup
inetd
init
inotifyd
insmod
install
ionice
ip
ipaddr
ipcalc
ipcrm
ipcs
iplink
iproute
iprule
iptunnel
kbd_mode
kill
killall
killall5
klogd
last
length
less
linux32
linux64
linuxrc
ln
loadfont
loadkmap
logger
login
logname
logread
losetup
lpd
lpq
lpr
ls
lsattr
lsmod
lzmacat
lzop
lzopcat
makemime
man
md5sum
mdev
mesg
microcom
mkdir
mkdosfs
mkfifo
mkfs.minix
mkfs.vfat
mknod
mkpasswd
mkswap
mktemp
modprobe
more
mount
mountpoint
mt
mv
nameif
nc
netstat
nice
nmeter
nohup
nslookup
od
openvt
passwd
patch
pgrep
pidof
ping
ping6
pipe_progress
pivot_root
pkill
popmaildir
printenv
printf
ps
pscan
pwd
raidautorun
rdate
rdev
readlink
readprofile
realpath
reformime
renice
reset
resize
rm
rmdir
rmmod
route
rpm
rpm2cpio
rtcwake
run-parts
runlevel
runsv
runsvdir
rx
script
scriptreplay
sed
sendmail
seq
setarch
setconsole
setfont
setkeycodes
setlogcons
setsid
setuidgid
sh
sha1sum
sha256sum
sha512sum
showkey
slattach
sleep
softlimit
sort
split
start-stop-daemon
stat
strings
stty
su
sulogin
sum
sv
svlogd
swapoff
swapon
switch_root
sync
sysctl
syslogd
tac
tail
tar
taskset
tcpsvd
tee
telnet
telnetd
test
tftp
tftpd
time
timeout
top
touch
tr
traceroute
true
tty
ttysize
udhcpc
udhcpd
udpsvd
umount
uname
uncompress
unexpand
uniq
unix2dos
unlzma
unlzop
unzip
uptime
usleep
uudecode
uuencode
vconfig
vi
vlock
volname
watch
watchdog
wc
wget
which
who
whoami
xargs
yes
zcat
zcip
```

Great stuff - you won't need any computer but your phone, anymore!